# Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0] // NativeScript

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, macos, nativescript

I am actually creating an app with the JS framework NativeScript.
I just pull the latest push, then run for the fist time on this new MAC (High Sierra, MacBook Pro early 2015).
My teammate is working on linux so he is using Android Studio and there is no segFault on his app on Android. I am on Mac so I needed xcode for the emulator, anyway.. (Xcode 9.0)

As you read : " Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0] "

this appears when I run the app, so the emulator starts then building many things and install the app on the emulator but since I tried to open the app from the emulator the error occurs...

I don't know what's happening !

**EDIT** :

I am using firebase with the plugin for nativeScript, I figured out that when I comment in app.js the firebase.init and when I comment in views/login the export.loaded where i am using the firebase.init, the error stop to occur, but i have no database for my app so this is a problem. Anyone has an idea ?

BTW, when I try to open any projects with Xcode, especially my App (in ~/Desktop/MyApp), an error occurs and Xcode just saying that it can't open my project.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Topic resolved, I just reinstalled everything from the beginning and everything worked fine.

thanks